# Flutter LateInitializationError on startup

Tags: flutter, dart

In my Flutter app, there is a LateInitializationError at first but after a second the error is no longer there. Here is a small gif showing the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/htJXC.gif

This is the full error it gives:

```dart
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following LateError was thrown building HomePage(dirty, state: HomePageState#cbe92):
LateInitializationError: Field 'ilkSayiOynama' has not been initialized.

The relevant error-causing widget was: 
  HomePage file:///C:/Users/emirs/AndroidStudioProjects/tahmin_oyunu/lib/main.dart:56:15
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      ilkSayiOynama (package:tahmin_oyunu/home.dart)
#1      HomePageState.build (package:tahmin_oyunu/home.dart:168:83)
#2      StatefulElement.build (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4691:27)
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4574:15)
#4      StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4746:11)
```

My initState():

```dart
  @override
  void initState() {
    checkIfEmpty();
    _bannerAd = BannerAd(
      adUnitId: "ca-app-pub-/------",
      request: AdRequest(),
      size: AdSize.banner,
      listener: BannerAdListener(
        onAdFailedToLoad: (ad, err) {
          print('Failed to load a banner ad: ${err.message}');
          ad.dispose();
        },
      ),
    );
    _bannerAd.load();
    super.initState();
  }
```

The `checkIfEmpty` function:

```dart
checkIfEmpty() async {
    SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var list = prefs.getString("bilgiler");

    if (list == null) {
      var bilgiler = {
        "para": 150,
        "anahtar": false,
        "ilkSayiOynama": 10,
        "ikinciSayiOynama": 10,
        "ucuncuSayiOynama": 50,
        "ilkSayiKatOran2": 0,
        "ikinciSayiKatOran2": 0,
        "ucuncuSayiKatOran2": 0,
        "ilkSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
        "ikinciSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
        "ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
        "anahtarYazi": "Satın Alınmadı"
      };

      prefs.setString("bilgiler", jsonEncode(bilgiler));

      para = 150;
      ilkSayiOynama = 10;
      ikinciSayiOynama = 10;
      ucuncuSayiOynama = 50;
      anahtar = false;
      anahtarYazi = "Satın Alınmadı";

      ilkSayiKatOran2 = 0;
      ikinciSayiKatOran2 = 0;
      ucuncuSayiKatOran2 = 0;

      ilkSayiparaKaybetme =  0;
      ikinciSayiparaKaybetme = 0;
      ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme = 0;
      setState(() {});
    } else {
      var listJson = jsonDecode(list);

      para = listJson["para"];
      ilkSayiOynama = listJson["ilkSayiOynama"];
      ikinciSayiOynama = listJson["ikinciSayiOynama"];
      ucuncuSayiOynama = listJson["ucuncuSayiOynama"];
      anahtar = listJson["anahtar"];
      anahtarYazi = listJson["anahtarYazi"];

      ilkSayiKatOran2 = listJson["ilkSayiKatOran2"];
      ikinciSayiKatOran2 = listJson["ikinciSayiKatOran2"];
      ucuncuSayiKatOran2 = listJson["ucuncuSayiKatOran2"];

      ilkSayiparaKaybetme =  listJson["ilkSayiparaKaybetme"];
      ikinciSayiparaKaybetme = listJson["ikinciSayiparaKaybetme"];
      ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme = listJson["ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme"];
      setState(() {});
    }
  }
```

My `build` function:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Functions functions = Functions();

    return Scaffold(
      body: GestureDetector(
        behavior: HitTestBehavior.opaque,
        onTap: () {
          FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(FocusNode());
        },
         child: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Center(
              child: Column(
                children: [
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15, 15, 15, 0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 117,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextField(
                                  controller: s1,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "1.Sayı",
                                    helperText: "1 - 3 Arasında \nOynama Hakkı : $ilkSayiOynama\n$s1Tahmin",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 117,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextField(
                                  controller: s2,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "2.Sayı",
                                    helperText: "1 - 5 Arasında \nOynama Hakkı : $ikinciSayiOynama\n$s2Tahmin",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ),
                        ),
                        FittedBox(
                          fit: BoxFit.fitWidth,
                          child: Container(
                            width: 117,
                            child: Column(
                              children: [
                                TextField(
                                  controller: s3,
                                  keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                                    hintText: "3.Sayı",
                                    helperText: "1 - 7 Arasında \nOynama Hakkı : $ucuncuSayiOynama\n$s3Tahmin",
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ],
                            ),
                          ) ,
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 45),
                    child: Container(
                      width: 100,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          TextField(
                            controller: oran,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Oran"),
                          ),

                          TextField(
                            controller: miktar,
                            keyboardType: TextInputType.number,
                            decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: "Miktar"),
                          )
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(25,25,0,0),
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                      children: [
                        Text("Para : $para", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20)),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 10),
                    child:ElevatedButton(
                        onPressed: () {
                          functions.oynaButton(context);
                          setState(() {});
                        },
                        child: Text("Oyna")),
                  ),

                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 25),
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        Text("Satın Alınanlar", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 27),),

                        Padding(padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10,13,0,0),
                          child: Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                child: Text("3.Sayi 2X Oran : $ucuncuSayiKatOran2",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child: Text("3.Sayi 2X Oran : $ucuncuSayiKatOran2",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child: Text("3.Sayi 2X Oran : $ucuncuSayiKatOran2",
                                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),
                                ),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child: Text("1.Sayı Para Kaybetmeme : $ilkSayiparaKaybetme", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child: Text("2.Sayı Para Kaybetmeme : $ikinciSayiparaKaybetme", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child: Text("3.Sayı Para Kaybetmeme : $ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16)),
                              ),

                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 11),
                                child:Text("Anahtar : $anahtarYazi \n", style: TextStyle(fontSize: 16),),
                              ),

                            ],
                          ),
                        ) ,
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                      child: Container(
                        width: _bannerAd.size.width.toDouble(),
                        height: _bannerAd.size.height.toDouble(),
                        child: AdWidget(ad: _bannerAd),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 15, bottom: 10),
                    child: Align(
                      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                      child: ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                          showDialog(
                            context: context,
                            builder: (BuildContext context) {
                              return AlertDialog(
                                title: Text("Emin misin?"),
                                content: Text("Bu tüm değerlerini sıfırlar!"),
                                actions: [
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: Text("Hayır"),
                                    onPressed: () {
                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  ),
                                  TextButton(
                                    child: Text("Evet"),
                                    onPressed: () async {
                                      var prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
                                      var list = prefs.getString("bilgiler");
                                      var bilgiler = jsonDecode(list!);

                                      bilgiler = {
                                        "para": 150,
                                        "anahtar": bilgiler["anahtar"],
                                        "ilkSayiOynama": 10,
                                        "ikinciSayiOynama": 10,
                                        "ucuncuSayiOynama": 50,
                                        "ilkSayiKatOran2": 0,
                                        "ikinciSayiKatOran2": 0,
                                        "ucuncuSayiKatOran2": 0,
                                        "ilkSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
                                        "ikinciSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
                                        "ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme": 0,
                                        "anahtarYazi": bilgiler["anahtarYazi"]
                                      };

                                      prefs.setString("bilgiler", jsonEncode(bilgiler));

                                      para = 150;
                                      ilkSayiOynama = 10;
                                      ikinciSayiOynama = 10;
                                      ucuncuSayiOynama = 50;
                                      ilkSayiKatOran2 = 0;
                                      ikinciSayiKatOran2 = 0;
                                      ucuncuSayiKatOran2 = 0;
                                      ilkSayiparaKaybetme = 0;
                                      ikinciSayiparaKaybetme = 0;
                                      ucuncuSayiparaKaybetme = 0;

                                      setState(() {});
                                      functions.showSnackBar(context, "Değerleriniz sıfırlandı");

                                      Navigator.pop(context);
                                    },
                                  )
                                ],
                              );
                            },
                          );
                        },
                        child: Text("Sıfırla") ,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),

                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      );
  }
```

As you can see, `ilkSayiOynama` gets initialized no matter what. The problem is that it shows the error, and then the error is gone and I can use `ilkSayiOynama` without any problems. I put the `checkIfEmpty();` function before `super.initState()` but that did not work either. I'm thinking that the `build` function is trying to access `ilkSayiOynama` before its initialized. How can I stop this from happening?

Comment: _bannerAd.load(); is it an async function?

Comment: `ilkSayiOynama` is initialized only *after* the `await` for the asynchronous function completes, not before `build()` runs.  Use a `FutureBuilder` that waits for `checkIfEmpty` to complete.

Comment: @jamesdlin How can I use the function inside a FutureBuilder? Do I need to put the checkIfEmpty function as a future for the FutureBuilder?

Comment: You have to save the `Future` returned by `checkIfEmpty`, pass it to the `FutureBuilder`, and let the `FutureBuilder`'s callback build the dependent part of the widget tree.  Also see [What is a Future and how do I use it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63017280/)

Comment: @jamesdlin Thank you! FutureBuilder fixed the issue.